# How full does the old generation have to be to trigger a major GC cycle?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, size, heap-memory

I am working on resolving a high garbage collection utilization rate in our production environment, and was wondering if setting a large heap size guaranteeing that the old generation will never be really filled up would prevent triggering a major GC cycle.

For that to be true, I imagine that there is a certain threshold mark at which a major GC cycle gets triggered.  If this assumption is true, can someone please let me know what that number is?  If not, I would appreciate an explanation of how these major cycles are actually triggered and if my large heap strategy has a potential of working.

Comment: which version of Java, specifically?

Comment: @bobdabelina you should really accept the answer.. *if* you use CMS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Concurrent Mark Sweep

Assuming you use Concurrent Mark Sweep collector (e.g. `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC`), it, by default, starts to collect concurrently when OldGen reaches **70%**. But it is tunable via `CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction` e.g.:

```
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=42
```

this will start concurrent collection at 42% vs. the default 70%

Note that `CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction` will only be in effect for the first collection. To enable it "for good" add `UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly`:

```
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=42
```

---

### Max Heap Free Ratio

You can also look at `MaxHeapFreeRatio` that is a maximum percentage of heap free *after* GC to avoid shrinking, which is set to **70%** by default, but you can change that as well:

```
-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=42
```

---

### Getting to the bottom

But before changing any params, it would be good to understand the reason for this "high garbage collection utilization rate":

- Why does it get to the OldGen if it needs to be collected so often?
- Are you capturing streaming data?
- Does a heap size too small for a problem?
- Does it make sense to store this particular data off heap?
- etc..

Since usually JVM is quite good at knowing *when* to collect, and it's only getting better.

---

other [HоtSpot VM options](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html)

Comment: Thanks Tolitius.  We are indeed using CMS and the answer is very helpful.

Comment: Thanks. The way `CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction` is for old generation, is there any parameter for young generation? I am trying to understand at what % of young generation, a minor GC is triggered...