# What is the threshold for CMS Old GC to be triggered

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection

The JVM flags (memory) for our server is as below

```
-Xms2048m
-Xmx2048m
-Xss512k
-XX:+UseParNewGC
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled
-XX:NewSize=128m
-XX:MaxNewSize=128m
-XX:PermSize=128m
-XX:MaxPermSize=128m
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

I need to find out when exactly the Old GC triggered i.e Is it related to the percentage of total heap memory used?.

I did some tests with huge loads and monitored the app using **visualVM** and **jstat**. But I could not find out any pattern when actually the old gc is triggered. Sometimes gc is triggered when the oldgen is utilized only 27.13 % and then 76.02 %, 92.61 % etc.

Can someone give some hints about what actually triggers the old gc?

I need to find out the memory threshold that triggers an old gc. With this I am able to set some high memory alert warning in server (the correct settings rules out any false alerts to be triggered)?

This post says gc will be triggered when old gc usage is 70% by default. But not seems to be working in this case.
[How full does the old generation have to be to trigger a major GC cycle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23176974/how-full-does-the-old-generation-have-to-be-to-trigger-a-major-gc-cycle)

Answer (score 2):

The other question you have linked already provides the answer: A concurrent cycle is triggered by heap occupancy if you explicitly configure it through the `UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly` and `CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction` options.

Otherwise heuristics are used by the JVM which contiously adjust the thresholds at runtime based on how previous collections performed.

Comment: thanks for the answer. In my case CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction is not set, so I guess it might be the default 68 %. And I think as you said JVM uses some heuristics to decide the threshold. So are you saying I do not have a way to decide the threshold beforehand?

Comment: I'm saying you should set those settings.